# URP Simple Lit Emission not working on build iOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, urp

When working with a material with URP Simple Lit which has Emission turned on, the material glows fine in Editor View as well as Game View, BUT when building the project and running in on iOS, the material emission does not work.

The Base Map works fine and has the proper color but Emission Map seems to be completely ignored.

Any recommendations or ideas as to why this might be happening?

I have spent several days now looking for different solutions but nothing seems to work.

Thing's I've tried:

- Added "URP Simple Lit" to Always Include Shaders in Project Settings
- Added a small cube with this shader (As apparently that was the fix for some Standard shaders)
- Tried enabling material Emission keyword from script

Below you can observe the Settings of the material, as well as screenshots for both the game running in an iOS device and the game running in Game View inside Unity.

[image: Emissive material settings]

[image: Game in game view]

[image: Game in iOS Device]

Comment: Do you have HDR or PostProcessing enabled/disabled for those device types? (Check Player Settings)

Comment: I am kind of a newbie to Unity. Can you please refer me to where I can find that?

I checked under Edit > Project Settings > Player and I don't see HDR option. I checked under Resolution and Presentation as well as Other Settings but I am not seeing that option

Comment: UPDATE: I did check this. Since URP uses a Scriptable Render, these settings weren't in there but I made sure HDR was on for URP and also made sure Post-process Volume contains a Bloom override. But still, that does not show on the mobile device. Works fine on game view

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you turn on HDR in Low/Medium Quality URP setting. Android will switch to low/medium if it thinks the phone cannot run High Quality.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).